# JS как вызвать функцию из массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, у меня есть глобальный массив **callbacks**, внутри него хранится функция, которую мне надо исполнить внутри события .on("click"). Как собственно вызвать эту функцию из массива **callbacks**? Если бы это был не массив, а переменная я бы просто вызвал её так: callbacks(); Однако, с массивом такое не проканает.

Comment: Что то не понятно ваша задача, можете пример кода показать откуда и что хотите получить

Comment: callbacks[2]() ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно указать индекс функции в массиве.

Например:

```
.on("click", function(){
  window.callbacks[0]();
});
```

Или можно сразу передать эту функцию:

```
.on("click", window.callbacks[0]);
```

Можно вытащить функцию в переменную:

```
var func = callbacks[0];
func();
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.